# Store Objective C object in C++ data structure with strong reference

Tags: c++, objective-c

I need to store pointers to some Objective C instances in a C++ object (without going into much detail, I must do so). The C++ class is a AVL tree algorithm and allows to insert, find and remove entries.

How should I implement the lifecycle management correctly?

Comment: Have you searched for solutions on internet yet? Sources like, https://juliankniephoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/revisiting-using-objective-c-objects-in-c-classes-in-the-age-of-arc/

Comment: I came across that site, it doesn't help in my case. I get various Objective C objects provided from the frontend app to my library code, and I cannot wrap them like that. I would probably instead have to wrap all objects using another NSObject which keeps a strong ref to these objects and avoid ARC on this object. Something like that.